# spark select and add columns with alias

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, bigdata

I want to select few columns, add few columns or divide, with some columns as space padded and store them with new names as alias. For example in SQL should be something like:

```
select "   " as col1, b as b1, c+d as e from table
```

How can I achieve this in Spark?

Answer (score 17):

You can also use the native DF functions as well. For example given:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df1 = Seq(
 ("A",1,5,3),
 ("B",3,4,2),
 ("C",4,6,3),
 ("D",5,9,1)).toDF("a","b","c","d")
```

select the columns as:

```
df1.select(lit(" ").as("col1"),
           col("b").as("b1"),
           (col("c") + col("d")).as("e"))
```

gives you the expected result:

```
+----+---+---+
|col1| b1|  e|
+----+---+---+
|    |  1|  8|
|    |  3|  6|
|    |  4|  9|
|    |  5| 10|
+----+---+---+
```

Comment: can you show how to convert string into int and then add two columns and how to do ((col1/col2)*100)

Comment: If you have a `string` column you can convert into `int` using `col("a").cast("int")`. Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 6):

with Spark-SQL, you can do the same way.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df1 = Seq(
 ("A",1,5,3),
 ("B",3,4,2),
 ("C",4,6,3),
 ("D",5,9,1)).toDF("a","b","c","d")

df1.createOrReplaceTempView("table")
df1.show()

val df2 = spark.sql("select ' ' as col1, b as b1, c+d as e from table ").show()
```

Input:

```
    +---+---+---+---+
    |  a|  b|  c|  d|
    +---+---+---+---+
    |  A|  1|  5|  3|
    |  B|  3|  4|  2|
    |  C|  4|  6|  3|
    |  D|  5|  9|  1|
    +---+---+---+---+
```

Output :

```
+----+---+---+
|col1| b1|  e|
+----+---+---+
|    |  1|  8|
|    |  3|  6|
|    |  4|  9|
|    |  5| 10|
+----+---+---+
```