# How to add intermediate columns in dataframe selections?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark

Using Spark 2.2  with spark-shell, and try both `toDF` and `toDS`.

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Long)
val df = Seq( Person("Michael", 0), Person("Andy", 30), Person("Justin", 19) ).toDS()
```

This is working fine:

```
df.select("age", "name").show
df.select("age", "name").withColumn("foo",lit("-")).show
```

but using [this syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52539903/287948) is not working:

```
df.select( "age", lit("-").as("foo"), "name" ).show
```

how to use column functions or column constants?

I need to change order of columns and add some intermediary columns.

Comment: You can do withColumn then select to get correct order

Comment: @firsni, yes, seems elegant solution (!), you can post as answer... Or I can **delete** this "for dummy" question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the example and supposing spark-shell context, this query solves the problem:

```
        df.withColumn("foo",lit("-")). select("name","foo","age")
```

Comment: Some errors on my spark-shell. *"error: not found: value name"*, must use `select("name")` not `select(name)`.    *"cannot resolve '`foo`' given input columns"*, must use `withColumn("foo",lit("-"))` not `withColumn("age",lit("-").as("Foo"))`.

Comment: The solution was `df.withColumn("foo",lit("-")). select ("name","foo","age")`

Comment: Ok because I use my phone. I didn't know the order you want. Thx